# App store app rejected 5.2.2 your app requests, displays, or distributes third-party account information

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, mac-appstore, app-store-connect

hi my app rejected by app store team because of following reason

"Your app contains content or features that may violate the rights of one or more third parties. Specifically, your app requests, displays, or distributes third-party account information in order to allow unauthorized access to said service.

Your app and its contents should not infringe upon the rights of another party. In the event your app infringes another party’s rights, you are responsible for any liability to Apple because of a claim."

My app is price comparison app that aggregates products from various e-commerce stores across India.

Also I use SafariView controller for opening external url to one sites when user clicks on Buy button. Is in app safari view controller causing any issue or it's just related to third party data. Should I use **UIApplication.shared.open** instead to open external link. how this cab be fixed? has any other aggregator app has faces similar issue? Please let me know.

Also if it is related to third party data how to fix this? As site has already allowed us to display its data under affiliate program.

Comment: Did you submit that permissin document with your app during the review process?  You're relying on content owned by other companies so you need their permission.

Comment: No we provided url related to affliate program but got rejected.

Comment: Then, according to Apple's view, you don't have permission to the content.  The reject states "Specifically, your app requests, displays, or distributes third-party account information in order to allow unauthorized access to said service."  You're allowing people to make a purchase or login through your app?

Comment: Yeah opening in safari view controller user might login after going to site should i redirect user to external browser instead? But i guess after redirecting it to external browser they might raise design issue

Comment: You need to follow the Apple guidelines for logging someone into an external site.  This site isn't for coding questions, you'll get better responses on how to code this on StackOverflow.